# Does loginuid have any impact on process limits?

Tags: linux, sudo, login, limit

On CentOS/RHEL 6, when I start my daemon as root user, I see `/proc/<pid>/loginuid` of the process as 0 and when I start it through sudo, I see loginuid of the sudo  user. Even if I do sudo su - to become root, I see loginuid of the sudo user. My doubt is whether the process limits of open files, memory etc change when loginuid is non-root ? Or for that matter any other factor which causes performance drop when loginuid is non-root ?

Comment: Are you asking about `ulimit` of sudo user's process?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the login UID doesn't change after `sudo` or `su` is the whole point of a having login UID, separate from the real and effective UIDs. It's meant for logging purposes.

Neither the login UID nor any other UID of a process has a direct impact on a process's limits or performance.

Limits are set by the program that logs you in. After that, they are inherited by all the programs in the session, even if you call `sudo` or `su` or some other program to change to another user. A program can change the limits that apply to it, but only up to a point: there's a soft limit, which programs can change, and a hard limit, which programs can't change unless running as root¹. Normal programs don't change their limits.

¹  <sub>or having the appropriate capability, which normally only root has.</sub>